# Could not find "store" in either the context or props when showing modal

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

This is my start point of the app:

```
const App = () => (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <StackNav />
    </Provider>
);

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp', () => App);
```

For the StackNav I have the following configuration:

```
const routeConfiguration = {
    TO_LOGIN: { screen: Login },
    TO_HOME: { screen: Home },
};

const stackNavigatorConfiguration = {
    headerMode: 'screen',
    navigationOptions: {
        header: null,
    }
};
```

Inside Login screen I show a modal inside which I cannot use the connect method of react-redux. This is the full error:

[image]

Here is how I am trying to use it:

```
class SignModal extends Component {

}

export default connect()(SignModal);
```

What can be the reason? Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modal will exist outside the current component hierarchy. The pattern is called a `Portal`. This means that it cannot access the React context, hence cannot find the Redux store. Currently there is no API in React Native to fix this. You need to explicitly pass the store as a prop.

Probably better to just connect the component which has the Modal, and pass needed values as props to inner component.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
export const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    //what you want from the store
  }
}
```

and then

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SignModal);
```

Comment: Do you have access to the store inside LoginScreen?

Comment: I have access to it even in the SignModal if your idea is to pass it as a prop. The reason why I need connect() method to work is because when there is a change in the store the component rerender itself which is what I need in this case (controlling the preloader).

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. Use your modal as a view component and create a connected container component.

```
// components/Modal.js

class Modal extends Component {
    render() {
        <Modal />
    }
}

export default Modal
```

```
// containers/ModalContainer

import Modal from "../components/Modal"

const mapState = state => ...
const mapDispatch = dispatch => ...

export default connect(mapState, mapDispatch)(Modal)
```

Import Modal from "../containers/ModalContainer" when you use it.